# Having trouble writing a jquery to change navbar from clear to white on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have searched google and this forum, and there have been a few mentions of this topic but the answers given all varied, and none seemed to work for me.  I am very new to coding so I apologize if this is extremely obvious.  I have tried multiple different options, and I just can't seem to get it.  My site I am working on is https://essentialcleaning.solutions and here is the code I am trying:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var windowWidth = $(this).width();
  var windowHeight = $(this).height();
  var windowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();


    if(windowScrollTop>60){
        $('.x-navbar-fixed-top').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 100, 255, 0.5)');
    $('.x-navbar').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 100, 255, 0.5)');
    $('.x-navbar-inner').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 100, 255, 0.5)');
  };
});
```

I tried 3 differnt lines because I am not 100% sure what the navbar is called, I am seeing a few different options when I select it with developer tools, I am working with a theme, X theme from themeco.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you it is that you want to get right. As in, what is the desired behavior.

Comment: You shouldn't have to monitor scroll to change the background on scroll. The class of the navbar changes on scroll to `.x-navbar.x-navbar-fixed-top`. So you can set the default/initial background using `.x-navbar { background-color: white; }` and change the color when it's fixed by setting `.x-navbar.x-navbar-fixed-top { background-color: pink; }`

Comment: I apologize, I want to go from a clear navbar, to a white navbar on scroll.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your input, so you are saying that instead of listening for the scroll action, that the actual class of the navbar is changing already on scroll, so I can just use that?  So I guess my next question would be, how can I animate that so it is a smooth transition, not just an instant change from clear to white? This website is made using the same theme I am using, what they have is exactly what I am going for... https://thecuratedtravel.com/ Thank you again